# sequence in DB2 generates duplicate values

Tags: db2, sequence

My application uses DB2 data base. I had created a sequence for my table to generate the primary key,it was working fine uptill today, but now it seems to be generating existing values and I am getting DuplicateKeyException while inserting values. After a bit of googling I found that we can reset the sequence again. 
Could some one please help me with the best possible option as I have not worked with sequences much and the things to consider while going with that approach.
If I have to reset the sequence then what should be the best way to do it and again points to consider before doing so.Also it would be great to know what could be the reason behind the issue that I am facing so that I can take care of it in future.

Just for information the max value assigned while creating the sequence has not yet reached.

Thanks a lot in advance.

Comment: Check out the `ALTER SEQUENCE` statement in the manual for your DB2 version and platform.

Comment: This shouldn't be possible.  Sequences are guaranteed to generate sequential values (to the ending limit).  More likely, something else is inserting values ahead of the sequence, so there are "duplicates" by the time the sequence reaches those values.  Sequences do _not_ validate that the destination hasn't gotten the value (not possible, for a number of reasons).

Comment: @Clockwork-Muse  If you use the OS to populate or copy the tables all bets are off and sequences will be out of sync.  You then need to use alter sequence to correct them.  AFAIK you can also mess up a sequence by insert non null values into a sequence column and as long as there unique DB2 will accept them and not update the next sequence number.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ALTER SEQUENCE SCHEMA.SEQ_NAME RESTART WITH NUMERIC_VALUE;

this was required in my case i.e restarting the sequence with a value higher then the current max value of the id field for which the sequence was being used.

The NUMERIC_VALUE denotes the value which is higher then current max value for my sequence generated field.

Hope it will be helpful for others.

The cause probably for this issue was manual insertion of records in the db.